# Изображение мигает, когда подгружается

Tags: reactjs, api

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно организовать загрузку двух картинок с api, при первой загрузке страницы.

Есть определенная карточка, в нее загружается картинка при первой загрузке страницы, но при наведении картинка подгружается с api и из-за этого происходит flick эффект, подскажите пожалуйста как его можно избежать ?

```
  const [bgImage, setBgImage] = useState(`${API_ROOT}api/${image}`);
  const handleMouseEnter = () => {
    isBrowser && setBgImage(`api/${image_hover}`);
  };
  const handleMouseLeave = () => {
    isBrowser && setBgImage(`api/${image}`);
  };

<div
   className={styles.services}
   onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
   onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
   >
     <ImgPreload src={bgImage} />
</div>
```

Потому что при повторном наведении, т.к. он уже загрузил картинку в кэш все уже хорошо. Поэтому надо сделать так, чтоб он при первой же загрузке страницы сразу подгружал и hover вместе с обычной картинкой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заставьте браузер сразу загрузить все изображения.

Сделать это можно с помощью useEffect, когда компонент монтируется в DOM:

```
useEffect(() => {
    function preload(path) {
        const img = new Image();
        img.src = path;
    }
    preload(`${API_ROOT}api/${image}`);
    preload(`${API_ROOT}api/${image_hover}`);
}, []);
```

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, я буквально недавно пришел в react  и еще не особо понимаю все. Мне получается надо из usestate убрать `${API_ROOT}api/${image}`, и так же из setBgImage `${API_ROOT}api/${image_hover}`, но тогда как поместить элементы из useeffect туда ?

Comment: Нет, ничего убирать не надо. То что я предложил, это заставит браузер скачать сразу изображение с сервера и положить его в кэш.

Comment: В таком случае у меня получилась вот такая структура 
https://codepen.io/hikiasi/pen/gOKaVaB
Но он все-ровно моргает

Comment: Проверьте через консоль разработчика, что картинки скачиваются. Так же убедитесь, что ваш компонент ImgPreload обращается за картинкой по такому же пути. Отследите через консоль разработчика, что происходит при наведенеи(новое скачивание или идет взятие картинки из кэша)

Comment: Судя по всему картинки действительно загружаются, потому что в Network(Img) они все появляются с size - disk cache. Но вот как их правильно отобразить, потому что в ImgPreload src bgImage берется из usestate

Comment: Добавьте код ImgPreload, может там чего интересного у вас происходит

Comment: Обновил вопрос и добавил код

Comment: У вас там еще один вложенный компонент есть Image, это похоже на next.js... Я заглянул на [next/image](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image), во первых там есть ряд известных багов, + есть демо где, если перегружать страницу, видно, как картинка моргает... Видимо это фича такая, возможно есть рубильник в off. Я вам рекомендую там посмотреть, с next.js не работал. Возможно стоит убрать функцию загрузки и просто подставить src(картинка то уже загружена, ничего ждать не надо)

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое!!