# Как фоном подгружать статические файлы в React приложении?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, static, spa

У меня есть реакт приложение. В нем на некоторых страничках есть картинки и их много, и когда пользователь доходит до них, то они не успевают прогрузиться. Мне нужно сделать так чтобы при заходе на сайт фоном подгружались все статические файлы. Как это сделать?

Comment: [Заставьте браузер сразу загрузить все изображения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1462398/%d0%98%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f/1462422#1462422) - возможно, это ответ на ваш вопрос. Не видя вашего кода, точнее сказать сложно