# Проверка на загрузку и применение стилей

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Проблема следующая, необходимо перед тем как показать страницу пользователю подождать пока загрузится стили шрифты и т.п. и они применятся(пока это все грузится сайт выглядит кривым) и вместо этого показать Loader. вот что можно использовать чтобы проверить что все гуд?

Если к примеру использовать событие **load** то будет ожидаться загрузка изображений и т.п. и это не пригодно в моем случае.
пробовал использовать Suspense, но это как понимаю не работает на загрузку стилей только на компоненты

```
<Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
  <SomeComponent />
</Suspense>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться стандартным событием window.onload. Оно наступает тогда, когда все внешние ресурсы(стили, картинки) загружены.

Стоит сразу оговориться, что если есть загрузка стилей или картинок внутри самих компонентов, то придется их выносить наружу, иначе "моргание" будет.

В файле index.js, который ставит компонент App назначаем обработчик для события window.onload и по самому событию будем ставить компонент App.

До наступления события, будет установлен компонент лоадер.

```
window.onload = () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
}
// Компонент лоадера
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <div>Ждем загрузки</div>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

[Как подгрузить изображения к кэш в фоне](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1462398/)

Comment: смотрите, а если некоторые изображения и видео будут не доступны(скажем ресурс отсутствует) будет ли в таком случае отображена страница и есть ли какие то проблемы при постепенном загрузки медиа(загрузки при необходимости)

Comment: @Максим Если ресурс не доступен, то он не будет загружен, однако событие onload наступит. Если есть подгрузка каких либо ресурсов динамически, то тут либо для каждого изображения писать свои обработчики onload, либо заранее загрузить все media для вашего приложения.

Comment: благодарю вас за помощь)))

Comment: @SwaD, но ведь браузер и так будет ждать загрузку стилей. Для шрифтов есть свойство в css. Кажется, что этот код совершенно бесполезен?

Comment: @Qwertiy Да, действительно, браузер ждет стили и не запускает js код до полного скачивания. Однако это не работает с картинками. Видимо, хоть на первый взгляд, код и бессмысленным кажется, но помог ¯\\(ツ)/¯

Comment: @SwaD, во-первых, про js неправда. А во-вторых, откуда на странице картинки, если мы ещё ничего не рендерили?

Comment: @Qwertiy Код выше тестировал с картинкой в режиме slow 3g. Появлялся div ждем загрузки, после скачивания картинки, срабатывал onload. Если картинки убрать, добавить css(увеличил до 4мб) и в том же slow или fast 3g запустил, наблюдаю: js скачивается, рендера нет, затем докачивается css, ставится первый компонент, затем срабатывает onload и ставиться app. Если к div добавляем img большой, то наблюдаем: скачивается js, скачивается css, ставится компонент с "Ждем загрузки", начинает качаться изображение и потом onload и установка основного компонента.

Comment: @SwaD, а как на странице оказалась картинка, если render <App /> внутри onload? В `<div>Ждем загрузки</div>` картинок явно нет.

Comment: @Qwertiy Да, в коде ответа этого нет, однако, что бы протестировать решение, я картинки добавлял. Сразу за div ставил `<img/>`

Comment: @SwaD, но ведь в таком случае картинки всё равно вне App и для них неважно, когда появится App?

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну так можно вне app заставить браузер выкачать все нужные для app картинки и может еще какие внешние ресурсы, что бы app не ожидал после рендера загрузку их браузером и брал из кэша.